# How to compare the values of specified columns from two tables in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, compare, dolphindb

I want to compare the values of specified columns from two tables and output the difference. For example, table *A* and table *A1* share the same column “val1“ but have different column values, how to output their differences in DolphinDB?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Return only the rows where either a.val1 doesn't exist, or a1.val1 doesn't exist.

```
select coalesce(a.val1, a1.val1)
from a
full join a1 on a.val1 = a1.val1
where a.val1 is null or a1.val1 is null
```

You can also do `select a.val1, a1.val1 ...`, if you want do know which table each value comes from.